# ‘Edgy’ as in ‘edgy humour’?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do I properly translate the English word ‘edgy’, meaning ‘overly
provocative or unconventional’?  For example:

- > I hate your brother, he's always so edgy!
- > The film would be nice, but they tried too hard to be edgy, which
  >   really killed the mood for me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to [esperanto.SE]. Sorry, but I have to ignore your request to leave your question's source as XHTML. Stack Exchange's spirit is that user can improve each other's content, and unnecessary embedded HTML makes that much harder.

Comment: @das-g.  *Saluton*, and thanks for fixing the tag.  Just to clarify: this an invitation for me to *always* write in non-tagged Markdown on the Esperanto SE, and not just a one-off correction, right?

Comment: Saluton kaj bonvenon! Yes, please refrain from using HTML tags where the same can be achieved with tag-free MarkDown. (And for stuff that would only work with tags, most often those tags are filtered away by Stack Exchange, anyway, so there's not much use for them.) There _are_ some situations, where actually using HTML tags makes things simpler for all, but those are rare. When one of those situations occurs, feel free to use appropriate HTML tags, but otherwise please try to stick to MarkDown without HTML tags or at least as few tags as possible.

Comment: Komprenite, dankon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `konvenci/`. For example:

```
konvencirompa
nekonvencia
nekonvenciema
konvencilima
preterkonvencia
```

`spita` or `defia` could also cover it, either by themselves or in a compound word.

Comment: I like ‘*spita*’.  It feels like the right word for most contexts where ‘edgy’ is used in a negative sense.